# Xamarin iOS: Wait for HKHealthStore SaveObject to finish

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, healthkit

i am currently working on a problem which I can't solve alone. I try to integrate HealthKit in my app. The normal solution works perfect and I'm currently working on an error handling to inform the user if something went wrong. The problem is that the method "SaveObject()" seems to be asynchronous and if the success is set, the outer method has already returned false. I have no idea how to solve this problem. :-(

Below is a snippet of my code so far.

```
private bool _saveToHealth(Data d)
{
    HKHealthStore hkStore = new HKHealthStore ();
    bool isSuccessful = false;
    hkStore.SaveObject (d, (bool arg1, NSError arg2) => {
            isSuccessful = arg1;
    });
    return isSuccessful;
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure about the problem you experiencing: you call `_saveToHealth` and once `SaveObject()` is finishing with the save status (succeed or failed), `_saveToHealth` has already returned with false?

Comment: Yes that's true. isSuccessful is ALWAYS false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not really write code like this.   You need to restructure your code so that you handle the save state somewhere else.

As you pointed out, there is no guarantee that the delegate with the isSuccessful = arg1 will ever be executed before you reach the return.

Now, if the above call is being executed from an async method, you can call the Async version of that method:

```
async bool SaveToHealth (Data d)
{
     var hkStore = new HKHealthStore ();
     try {
          await hkStore.SaveObjectAsync (d);
          return true;
     } catch {
          return false;
     }
}
```

```

The async version of methods that have a  signature is mapped to throwing an exception on failure.

Comment: Works great for me. The method signature has to be "async Task<bool> SaveToHealth (Data d) and the calling method has to be defined like this: Task<bool> noErrorTask = SaveToHealth(item);
noError = noErrorTask.Result;

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not familiar with `Xamarin iOs`, and its capabilities, but I solved an issue similar to this in `Objective c` with the help of blocks. I'll provide here a code snippet of how I would do it in `Objective c`, and hopefully you can make the adjustments needed to your programming language:

```
- (void)saveToHealthData:(Data *)d WithCompletionHandler:( void ( ^ )(BOOL isSuccessful) )completionHandler
{
    HKHealthStore *hkStore = [HKHealthStore new];  
    BOOL isSuccessful = NO;
    [hkStore saveObject:d withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
         completionHandler(success);
    }];
}
```

In any case, you should consider having only 1 instance of the `HKHealthStore` and not instantiate one every time you call this method (or any method that saves or read data from the healthKit).

Hope it will help you.